Genus 0 curves on surfaces and the abc conjecture
One of the most obvious methods to prove that a given Diophantine equation $P(x_1, \dots, x_n)=0$ has infinitely many integer solutions is to find polynomials $P_1, \dots, P_n$ in one variable $u$, not all constant, such that $P(P_1(u), \dots, P_n(u))$ is identically $0$. For example, for equation
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=2
$$
this method works with $x=1-6u^3$, $y=-6u^2$, $z=1+6u^3$. For equation
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=3 \quad \quad \quad (*)
$$
such polynomials are conjectured to not exist, because if they would, they would likely to produce more small solutions. For equations like
$$
x^3y^2 = z^3 + 1 \quad \quad \quad (**)
$$
such polynomials are known to not exist, due to Mason–Stothers theorem, an analogue of abc conjecture for polynomials.
A natural generalization of this method is to find polynomials $P_1, \dots, P_n$ in two variables $u,v$, not all constant, such that
$$
Q(u,v) := P(P_1(u,v), \dots, P_n(u,v)) = 0
$$
has infinitely many integer solutions $(u,v)$. For example, for equation
$$
y^2 + xyz + x^3 - 2 = 0
$$
this method works with $x=6u^2+1$, $y=v$, $z=6u$. This reduces the equation to genus $0$ curve with infinitely many integer points $(u,v)$. Note that genus $0$ condition is necessary for the method to work because if genus is positive then $Q(u,v)=0$ can have at most finitely many integer solutions.
Now, if we could find polynomials $P_1,P_2,P_3$ in $(u,v)$ such that
$$
Q(u,v) = P_1(u,v)^3 + P_2(u,v)^3 + P_3(u,v)^3 - 3
$$
is a genus $0$ curve with infinitely many integer zeros, this would prove that (*) has infinitely many integer solutions. Further, if we find $P_1,P_2,P_3$ such that
$$
Q(u,v) = P_1(u,v)^3 P_2(u,v)^2 - P_3(u,v)^3 - 1
$$
is a genus $0$ curve with infinitely many integer zeros, this would prove that (**) has infinitely many integer solutions, disproving the abc conjecture.
I am interested whether there exist any method for searching such $P_i$ better than blindly trying all polynomials? I am also interested whether there is a deep reason (similar to Mason–Stothers theorem) that explains why such $P_i$ cannot exist for any equation that has finitely many integer solutions under the abc conjecture.

The Mason-Stothers argument works the same way. Any genus $0$ curve with infinitely many integer points has infinitely many rational points and thus is normalized by $\mathbb P^1$, i.e. parameterized by a rational parameter $t$. The missing points on $\mathbb P^1$ must form a divisor of degree $1$ or $2$, and be irreducible in the degree $2$ case. So in terms of the parameter $t$, the coordinates of the curve are rational functions whose denominators are powers of the same irreducible quadratic polynomial (or linear polynomial, but this reduces to the case of ordinary polynomials).
We obtain an equation $A + B = C$ where $A, B, C$ are rational functions whose denominators are powers of the same irreducible quadratic polynomial. The integer points will be those where the quadratic polynomial takes the value $\pm 1$ (or possibly some finite list of values). Thus, when we clear the denominators, we only multiply the values of $A,B, C$ at integer points by a bounded amount. So if finiteness was implied by $A,B,C$ before clearing denominators it will be implied after clearing denominators, and now one can apply the usual Mason-Stothers argument.

What is a reference that the polynomials are quadratic? I think the parametrization can be of arbitrary degree polynomials.

@joro  I'm not referring to the polynomials in the parameterization, but rather to the polynomial defining the points of P^1 that need to be removed for the parameterization map to be well-defined. These cannot have arbitrary degree without losing infinitely many rational points. If it's degree 3, after passing to a field where the polynomial splits, and changing variables so the 3 roots are 0, 1, infinity, you would get infinitely many solutions to the S-unit equation.

Thanks, I didn't know this. Is your answer valid for elliptic curves with infinitely many rational points?

@joro That would require parameterizing an affine equation with a projective elliptic curve, which is impossible. But there is a genus 1 curve version of the Mason-Stothers theorem (in fact the arbitrary genus version is in the original paper) that can be used for similar situations with homogeneous polynomials.

I wasted some electricity on a very similar problem
until I realized that if we fix all variables except one,
then the abc theorem for polynomials may imply non-existence
after parametrization of all the terms.
One potential approach for $Q(u,v) = P_1(u,v)^3 + P_2(u,v)^3 + P_3(u,v)^3 - 3$
is to work over $\mathbb{Q}[u,v,a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$ and chose bound
for the degrees of $P_i$. Treating the $a_i$ as variables, set
$P_i=\sum a_i u^k v^m$.
Set $Q(u,v)=F(u,v)G(u,v)$.
Set $F(u,v)=\sum a_i u^k v^m$ where $\deg_{u,v}(F)=2$.
Since $F$ is of degree $2$ in $u,v$ if it is non-singular, it is genus 0 curve.
Then equate all coefficients of $u,v$ which are polynomials in $a_i$.
You get system of non-linear equation over the rationals
(or the integers).
If you manage to solve the system, you get the needed identity.
